# DB2 Error USING STOGROUP "IBMSTOGROUP"

Tags: sql, db2

I am getting the following error after running...

```
CREATE REGULAR TABLESPACE "APPSPACE8KR" IN DATABASE PARTITION GROUP IBMDEFAULTGROUP 
     PAGESIZE 8192 MANAGED BY AUTOMATIC STORAGE 
     USING STOGROUP "IBMSTOGROUP" 
     AUTORESIZE YES 
     INITIALSIZE 32 M 
     MAXSIZE NONE 
     EXTENTSIZE 16
     PREFETCHSIZE 32
     BUFFERPOOL "BP8K"
     DATA TAG INHERIT
     OVERHEAD 10.670000
     TRANSFERRATE 0.040000 
     FILE SYSTEM CACHING  
     DROPPED TABLE RECOVERY ON;
```

**Error**: `SQL Error: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -104, SQLSTATE: 42601, SQLERRMC: USING STOGROUP "IBMSTOGROUP";BY AUTOMATIC STORAGE;<space>`

I tried searching for a solution but couldn't find any... Don't know whats causing the issue. Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which db2 version are you using? where did you get the ddl? it looks like you get the DDL from a recent version, and you are executing it in an older version.

Storage groups are new in version 10.1. If you are going to create a tablespace in the default storage group, it is not necessary to indicate it. Just remove that part.